# Send date parameters from datepicker without "/" on method GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a form with dates for booking, in the date field I use datepicker.
The objective this form is send parametres for a external URL.

I can send parametres with `method="GET"`, but have problem with date field because datepicker save parametres with slash "/", like:
dd/mm/yyyy

For this motive URL show encode like:

> CheckIn=**31%2F01%2F2015**&CheckOut=**18%2F03%2F2015**

when the correct link should be:

> CheckIn=**31012015**&CheckOut=**18032015**

Without the `%2F` encode.

--

How remove this encode from link?

My code:
http://jsfiddle.net/thallysondias/6e03wgLL/

Maybe using `str.replace`? But i dont know how use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleKatarn/6e03wgLL/2/

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $('#dpd1').val( $('#dpd1').val().replace(/\//g, '') );
    $('#dpd2').val( $('#dpd2').val().replace(/\//g, '') );
});
```

Comment: If one day you come to Lisbon, let me know, i buy you a beer, works fine. Thanks so much  :)